# OSError: Can not read file in context: \\?\C:\project\.gradle\6.6.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.lock

Tags: windows, docker, gradle, docker-compose

I have a Gradle project and I'm using docker in this project. When I execute the command `gradlew integrationTestDocker`, I get the error below.
`OSError: Can not read file in context: \\?\C:\project\.gradle\6.6.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.lock`

Comment: Same issue here.  It's a Gradle multiproject build, not containerized or using Docker.  Same Gradle version.  The file executionHistory.lock exists and I can open it in an editor (it's binary data), but Gradle barfs trying to read it at 51% through my tests.  Something to do with a class signing error.  Only happens on Windows (10) -- everything builds and runs fine on Linux and MacOS.

Comment: @user3562927 It looks like this issue happens because of the extra stuff added to path, if you see the path, it starts with "\\?\" which I think it's causing the issue. Not sure why executing this commands adds "\\?\" to the path.

Comment: @MoA The `\\?\ ` prefix indicates a name in the [Win32 namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces) and there is nothing wrong with that in itself. What do you get if you open a cmd prompt and run `type \\?\C:\project\.gradle\6.6.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.lock` at that point?

Comment: @dxiv You are right, when I executed the command, it printed some characters on the screen. With adding "\\?\" or without, the result was the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was reported before in Oct. 2018 ([issue 7043](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7043)) and Nov. 2019 ([issue 11520](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11520))

In both cases, the suggestion was to add `.gradle` to the `.dockerignore`, in order to make sure it is not part of the `docker build` context.
Plus [this comment](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7043#issuecomment-466499078):

> After few reboots and cleaning a repo described errors wasn't appear anymore.
> Seems like it was some local / windows issue

Comment: Thanks @VonC I just added `.dockerignore` file to the project and added `.gradle` inside this file. It worked!

Comment: Damn; I put up the bounty for this question, and the answer doesn't fix it for me because my issue is unrelated to Docker. Same issue -- can't read executionHistory.lock while I'm running my tests.  But not inside a container.  I guess I'll start a different bounty.  Note that I already had .gradle in .dockerignore, not that it matters since my issue is independent of Docker.

Comment: @user3562927 Interesting. I will be following your new bounty.