# gradle test on Windows 10: Couldn't read file content: executionHistory.lock

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-submodule project that I've recently begun building on Windows 10 (normally I build/run on MacOS.). On Windows, the tests for one particular module fail with this error:

`Couldn't read file content: 'C:\Users\Me\myproject\.gradle\6.7.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.lock'.`

I've run with `--scan` and it tells me the same thing in the build scan.

This happens with both Gradle 6.7.1 and Gradle 6.6.1.

It happens both for me (on a Windows 10 guest VM on VirtualBox, Mac host) and also for a teammate running a laptop with Windows 10 natively.

We are not using Docker. There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574922) that looks very similar to this one, but it is not the same issue.

The full stack trace from the build system is not terribly enlightening; here is the relevant bit:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't read file content: 'C:\msys64\home\Me\myproject\.gradle\6.7.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.lock'.
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.classpath.impl.ClasspathFingerprintingStrategy$ClasspathContentFingerprintingVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathFingerprintingStrategy.java:167)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.MissingFileSnapshot.accept(MissingFileSnapshot.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.CompleteDirectorySnapshot.accept(CompleteDirectorySnapshot.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.CompleteDirectorySnapshot.accept(CompleteDirectorySnapshot.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.CompleteDirectorySnapshot.accept(CompleteDirectorySnapshot.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.CompleteDirectorySnapshot.accept(CompleteDirectorySnapshot.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.classpath.impl.ClasspathFingerprintingStrategy.collectFingerprints(ClasspathFingerprintingStrategy.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultCurrentFileCollectionFingerprint.from(DefaultCurrentFileCollectionFingerprint.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.lambda$visitInputFileProperties$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:319)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$fingerprintInputFiles$3(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.visitInputFileProperties(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.fingerprintInputFiles(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:188)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionStateOp$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:40)
```

This problem is reliably reproducible, but it is a fairly large project, and creating a small repro case will not be practical.

I have tried all the obvious things:  clean source checkout, clean rebuild, completely nuking all gradle caches, etc.  Given that it happens to everyone who checks out my code base and tries to build it on Windows, I suspect it is a Gradle bug:  Gradle is failing to read its own internal tracking files.

The only anomaly I can think of is that I'm using JUnit 4 in the failing module, and JUnit 5 in some (but not all) of the other modules.  Some modules using JUnit 4 have passing tests.

Any advice or insights on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this in Gradle 6.7.1 with a very simple gradle build that looks like this:

Directory:

```
gradle_test/
   build.gradle
   Main.java
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

task simple(type: JavaCompile) {
    source = "Main.java"
    classpath = files(".")
    destinationDirectory = file("build")
}
```

Error:

```
> Task :simple FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':simple'.
> Couldn't read file content: 'D:\gradle_test\.gradle\6.7.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.lock'.
```

## Solution

I can't guarantee this is the case you're running into, but in my example build the error appears to happen because the build action itself is traversing into the `.gradle` folder looking for source files.

Moving `Main.java` into a `src` folder and adjusting the compilation properties accordingly fixes the problem.

I would check to make sure you don't have any tasks that are accidentally operating on the contents of the `.gradle` folder.

Comment: Interesting! I will take a look.